# try to write logout function

Tags: php, authentication

I wrote this code in php, but the file `userarea.php` sometimes work and sometimes not. Same with the function `logout.php`. How do I know it's working correctly or if there are any errors in my login file?

**confing.php:**

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$database = "DOD";
$user = "root";
$pass = "";

session_start();
$connection = mysqli_connect($host , $user , $pass , $database);

if(!$connection){
    die(mysqli_connect_error());
}

function logeedin(){
    if (isset ($_SESSION[('Username')]) && isset($_COOKIE[('Username')]))
        return TRUE;
}
?>
```

**login.php:**

```
<?php include('confing.php'); ?>
<html>
<body>
<form action="login.php" method="POST">
    Username : <input type="text" name="Username" /><br>
    Password : <input type="password" name="Password" /><br>
    Remember Me: <input type="checkbox" name="remmberme" /><br>
    <input type="submit" name="login" value="login" /><br>
</form>
<?php

if (logeedin() == TRUE){
    header("location : userarea.php");
}

if (isset($_POST['Login'])){
    $Username = $_POST['Username'];
    $Password = $_POST['Password'];
    $Remmember = $_POST['Remmember'];

    if(!empty($Username) && !empty($Password)){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM USER WHERE Username = '$Username'";
        $resulet = mysqli_query($connection,$sql);

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resulet)) {
            $db_password = $row["Password"];

            if($db_password ==  $Password)
                $login = TRUE;
            else
                $login = FALSE;
        }

        if ($login == TRUE){
            if(isset($Remmember)){
                setcookie('Username',$Username,time()+3600);
            }
            else {
                $_SESSION['Username']= $Username;
            }

            header ("location: userarea.php");
        }
        else {
            echo "Error";
        }
    }
    else{
        echo "Error";
    }
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

**logout.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
session_destroy();
setcookie("Username","",time()-6300);
header("location : login.php");
?>
```

**userarea.php**

```
<?php
include('confing.php');
if(!logeedin ()){
    header("location : login.php");
    exit(); 
}
?>  
welcome<br>
<?php echo $_SESSION['Username']; ?>
<a href= "logout.php"> Log out </a>
```

Comment: Why are you setting a cookie and session? Why not just stick with the session?

Comment: Anywhere you have a `header("location: XXX ");`, you need to 1) move it up above any browser output, 2) add `exit;` after it.

Comment: Also put `ini_set('display_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of your page(s). You should start to see errors/warnings.

Answer (score 0):

As Rasclatt said, mixing cookies and session is one thing. Try also `unset`'ting whole or particular array elements of `$_SESSION` array.

Destroying session by calling `session_destroy()` may be insufficient.

> How do I know it's working correctly or if there are any errors in my
>   login file?

Any did you find out why you have no errors displayed? Your code shows that you don't want them. Use `try/catch` block respectively, catch exceptions and `var_dump` them if needed. There's a heaps of improvements you could implement in your code.